# Hero Quest type games

Tags: recommendations

What other kinds of games are like Hero Quest...? In that, what other games are around with a degree of character development (although not the depth of something like D&D), items etc, that actually takes place on a board...?

I'm not chasing something like Munchkin Quest, as your character does not carry over from session to session.

Comment: Boy, there's a game that could use a re-release like Space Hulk did.

Comment: This has been the ultimate gateway game for getting into REAL RPG's.

Comment: closing this as not a great example of a shopping rec question.

Comment: I've never been convinced that shopping rec questions are necessarily a bad thing in any stackExchange site, but particularly in one devoted to board games perhaps there is an argument for allowing them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think of the greatest of this kind is [Descent: Journeys in the Dark](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17226/descent-journeys-in-the-dark) especially with [Road to Legend](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/29298/descent-the-road-to-legend) expansion which makes carrying over your characters between sessions slightly easier.

Comment: While these are good games, they may be a little hard-core for a casual Hero-Quest player.

Comment: should be Journeys in the Dark...?

Comment: OH YEAH. That's awesome. GOOD JOB

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 4):

There has been a [D&D board game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6366/dungeons-dragons-the-fantasy-adventure-board-game).

Comment: This is actually a lot like the old HeroQuest. Not too heavy, and very much fun!

Comment: The next expansion will allow you to carry your character much like HeroQuest too.  Excellent board game, worth its relatively inexpensive price.

Answer (score 1):

Descent is definitely the good current choice, especially with either of it's campaign expansions.  (You don't need both campaigns; they largely overlap so one is enough, unles you play it roughly every night for a year.)  Although, get *one* of the standard expansions Well of Darkness or Altar of Despair first; the campaign plays much better with the treachery cards from those expansions.

For a simpler, faster (and harder!) option, Descent's 'kid brother' Doom can work well.

(While we're on the family, Descent's older uncle Runebound is a bit less Hero-Questy but may still match what you're looking for.)

Answer (score 0):

Descent is a great game, but it's designed to play every level almost from scratch, unlike Hero Quest. While the Road to Legend expansion allows for a campaign, its game play suffers a lot and gets very boring soon.

Unlike Descent, in Doom you keep your character as the game progresses. It has similar, simpler, rules. If you don't mind dying over and over ^^

Answer (score -3):

A very similar is [World in Shades](http://www.indiegogo.com/World-in-Shades)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please have a look at our [How To Answer](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) page.  We vastly prefer substantive answers over short blurbs, which is probably why you have attracted a couple down votes.